# Intersperced Step Numbering

Tags: numbering

Im looking for a package or a way to handle numbering for items arbitrarily spaced through out a document, that can then be referenced later in the document.

My specific case is that I have a document of instructions, and I want to label all the measurement steps with a number (one that automatically increments like sections do), so I can reference that number on a page dedicated to recording measurement results.

I cannot figure out how to make an environment to handle this because the items are not all together.

Example of code.

```
\newenvironment{zz} %formating for section content, subsections, and their content
               {\list{}{
               \leftmargin=0.3in
               \rightmargin=0in
               \itemindent=0in
               \listparindent=0in
               }
               \item\relax}
               {\endlist}

\newenvironment{yy} %formating for subsubsections and their content
               {\list{}{
               \leftmargin=0in
               \rightmargin=0in
               \itemindent=0in
               \listparindent=0in}
               \item\relax
               }
               {\endlist}

\begin{document}
\HereIsSomeTitleStuff

\section{Instructions}
\begin{zz}
Its time for some background text. Leorium uipsume bla bla bla

\subsection{category A}

Here is some details on it.

More details and instructions

Measurement!!!!

More details

\subsection{category B}

Here is some details on it.

More details and instructions

Measurement!!!!

More details

\subsection {category C}

Here is some details on it.

More details and instructions

Measurement!!!!

More details

\end{zz}

\section{Intermediate part of the document}
\begin{zz}

Bla bla bla classified info goes here.

\end{zz}
\section{report forum}
\begin{zz}

space for first measurement

space for second measurement

space for third measurement
\end{zz}
\end document
```

See where I have "Measurement!!!!". I want those to be numbered in the final .pdf so I can reference the "step" number in the report form. `{zz}` is for paragraph formatting (indentation, hanging indentation).

Comment: So do you want some special numbering associated with the `zz` environment? What about `yy` (since you never use it)? Are these environments really necessary?

Comment: If you know of a better way to format sections, subsections, and all paragraphs, list, and tabular within a document I would love to know. Right now this method (which I got from here) doesn't work with figures and tables, so I dont use any of them.

Comment: What kind of formatting are you interested in? It seems like you're interested in indenting everything below a `\section`, right? What `\documentclass` are you using? Are you limited in the packages you can use?

Comment: Right now I am working in an article class. I have miktex installed. The document is typed entirely in unicode so I use xelatex to compile it.

Comment: Originally I was looking for a way to define document formatting parameters at the top of the document and have them automatically apply throughout the document. However, unless I am mistaken, I found that \sections and the like to not actually group (encapsulate parts of) the document. So I created a stripped down \quote environment called {zz} and I manualy encapsulate all the content held within a \section to indent it all. {yy} is the same thing for subsubsections. I have one more called {df} which is for creating definitions with subsequent lines indented. The solutions works pretty well.

Comment: Yes, sections are not really grouped entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a start to your measurement referencing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{measurement}
\newenvironment{measurement}
  {\par\refstepcounter{measurement}\noindent
   \textbf{Measurement~\themeasurement:}\quad\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\section{Instructions}
Its time for some background text. Leorium uipsume bla bla bla

\subsection{category A}

Here is some details on it.

More details and instructions

\begin{measurement}
Measurement!!!! \label{measurement1}
\end{measurement}

More details

\subsection{category B}

Here is some details on it.

More details and instructions

\begin{measurement}
Measurement!!!! \label{measurement2}
\end{measurement}

More details

\subsection {category C}

Here is some details on it.

More details and instructions

\begin{measurement}
Measurement!!!! \label{measurement3}
\end{measurement}

More details

\section{Intermediate part of the document}

Bla bla bla classified info goes here.

\section{report forum}

\begin{measurement}
space for first measurement. See measurement~\ref{measurement1}.
\end{measurement}

\begin{measurement}
space for second measurement. See measurement~\ref{measurement2}.
\end{measurement}

\begin{measurement}
space for third measurement. See measurement~\ref{measurement3}.
\end{measurement}
\end{document}
```

This is a very basic implementation that uses a counter spanning the entire document. If you wish to change the way the counter looks, update `\themeasurement`. If you wish to have the counter reset with (say) `\section`, that can also be done.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me how that works? Based upon the order I would have thought the number would be displayed first. You reference refstepcounter before \textbf{Measurement. Also, is ~\the a standard command? Because I dont see any variables called \themeasurement.

Comment: @Bob: `\refstepcounter` merely steps (increments) the counter *and* updates `\@currentlabel` - the thing that is used when you call `\label`. `\themeasurement` is the representation of the `measurement` counter. So, in sequence, we set a new paragraph `\par`, increment the `measurement` counter (and make it referenceable) via `\refstepcounter`, issue a `\noindent` so the paragraph is not indented, then set the heading in **bold** font via `\textbf` (this includes the title `Measurement` as well as the counter representation `\themeasurement` & colon), then a `\quad` space and ignore spaces.

Comment: @Bob: If you use `\newcounter{measurement}`, LaTeX creates a counter (variable) `\c@measurement` but also a representation of that counter in the form `\themeasurement` (default is set to `\arabic{measurement}`).